# Drawing a 3D Poisson Point Process with intensity $\lambda$

Tags: plotting, random

Can anyone suggest me a way of drawing a 3-dimensional Poisson Point Process (PPP) with intensity $\lambda$ in Mathematica. The points are located only in a half sphere. The 3-dimensional ball of radius $r$ is located in the origin. Let the radius $r$ be equal to 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mathematica has `RandomPoint` for picking a uniformly distributed point inside the specified region. As the average number of points for a uniform PPP in a bound region is proportional to it's volume, we have to variate `PoissonDistribution` with a given parameter and obtain this number of random points. All that is left is to draw it all together.

```
R = ImplicitRegion[
   x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1,
   {{x, 0, ∞}, y, z}
   ];
λ = 50;

pts = RandomPoint[
   R,
   RandomVariate[
    PoissonDistribution[λ*Integrate[1, {x, y, z} ∈ R]]
    ]
   ];

Show[{
  RegionPlot3D[
   R,
   PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.2]
   ],
  Graphics3D[
   Point[pts]
   ]
  }]
```

This code will produce the next picture:

[image]

Comment: What about the location (x, y, z of these points? Can I know that too?)

Comment: @Adil Those are stored in `pts` (check the documentation for RandomPoint).

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica 12.2 or later

[`PoissonPointProcess`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PoissonPointProcess.html) function is introduced in 2020 version (12.2)

```
SeedRandom[138];
\[Mu] = 1000;
dimension = 3;
pts = RandomPointConfiguration[PoissonPointProcess[\[Mu], dimension], 
  Ball[]]

Show[Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.2], pts["ObservationRegion"]}], 
 ListPointPlot3D@pts]
```

[image]